# C - assigning a value to a null pointer

Tags: c, pointers, nullpointerexception, null, null-pointer

Hi guys I'm new to C and pointers so I hope you'll forgive me.

I have the following code:

```
char *str = NULL;
*str = 'a';
printf("My string is :%s\n",str);
```

It compiles but I'm getting a segmentation error everytime. What is the cause of this and what how can I change it so that I can assign 'a' to my string?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the cause is "dereferencing a null pointer", here is a self-serve segmentation diagnosing tool. It can diagnose all the major causes of segmentation faults.  A live test of your code:
https://segfault.stensal.com/a/xORII1sQPhQnZai0

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
char *str = NULL;
```

The pointer str is not allocated yet. So you can not dereference it. Then you tried to deference by

```
*str = 'a';
```

The segmentation fault will occur.

If you want str with "a" value, you can do this way:

```
char *str = "a";
printf("My string is :%s\n",str);
```